# input type="text" переадресация по введённому тексту

Tags: php, html

Есть ссылка: [http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=ТУТ](http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%A2) НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА&text=ТУТ ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЯ

Самая задача:
Сделать форму на странице, в которую вводишь номер телефона и тебя перекидывает на данную страницу: [http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=НОМЕР](http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A0) КОТОРЫЙ ВВЁЛ В ФОРМУ&text=ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ СТАТИЧНЫЙ И ЗАДАН В КОДЕ СТРАНИЦЫ

Пробовал вот так, не получается:

```
<form id="search" action="//api.whatsapp.com/" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="send?phone"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: а если у пользователя нету ватсаппа ?

Comment: Это не важно. Боже.  Мне нужно просто чтобы работало и всё. У меня база номеров, у них у всех есть вацап.

Comment: это же для мобильной версии ? ведь не у всех ватсапп установлен в компе

Comment: Господи. Я ещё раз повторяюсь, мне нужно, чтобы это просто работало. Я открываю эту страницу через браузер в телефоне, ввожу туда номер, и меня перекидывает в приложение WhatsApp с прикреплённым сообщением, вот и всё. Хватит задавать, тупые, вопросы!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET['phone'])) {

$phone = $_GET['phone'];

header('Location:  http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone='.$phone.'&text=Hello world!');
exit;

}

?>


<form id="search" action="?" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="phone"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Так-с. А как параметр текста передать? Чтобы получилось ссылка такого типа:  http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=НОМЕР КОТОРЫЙ ВВЁЛ В ФОРМУ&text=ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ СТАТИЧНЫЙ И ЗАДАН В КОДЕ СТРАНИЦЫ

Comment: Подправил код, проверяй

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Вот пример:

```
<form id="search" action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send" method="get">
<input type="text" name="phone"/>
<input type="hidden" name="text" value="Ваш текст"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```